# Moving an object with geometric progression

Tags: math, formula, easing

I'm moving some object by it's X coordinate towards a target like this:

```
object.x += (target - object.x) * 0.1;  // Distance reduced by 10% each frame
```

I'm executing this each frame at 60 FPS. How to calculate time in seconds (or number of frames) needed to reach the target (be closer than given radius)?

I think it's called [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) or [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) but couldn't find how to apply these ideas and formulas to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is given by the comment:

```
// Distance reduced by 10% each frame
```

This can be used to construct the *explicit* formula for the final position:

```
final = abs(initial - target) * pow(1 - 0.1, frames);
```

The initial displacement is multiplied by 0.9 each frame (i.e. lowered by 10%). The power term accumulates these factors.

To invert the expression, use a **logarithm**:

```
frames = log(min_dist / abs(initial - target)) / log(1 - 0.1);
```

(Note that some languages have a variant of `log` which accepts a base; the above is the equivalent alternative in the case that your language does not.)

---

Edit: to calculate the multiplier:

```
mult = 1 - pow(min_dist / abs(initial - target)), 1 / frames);
```

Comment: The last formula gives me negative results. Maybe the last `log` should be `log(1 / 0.1)`?

Comment: @HankMoody that's not how log works; I've modified the formula, hopefully it gives the correct answer

Comment: OK, this is very helpful, thank you. Now, how to calculate the multiplier `0.1` value if the time (frames) is given?

Comment: @HankMoody added, although it should have been part of your original question

Comment: Thank you again. Yes, I've asked about time because I thought I'll be able to calculate the multiplier myself if I had time formula, but as it turned out I couldn't do that with my lack of knowledge about logarithms.